# Spring boot + Thymeleaf hang up on a submit post request

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring boot 1.4.3 with Thymeleaf 3. The problem is that from time to time, some requests on different submit forms are hanging up on a post request and it takes 4 to 5 seconds (normally 400 ms).

How can I debug this strange behavior, because it is not a regular problem?

Comment: Set a breakpoint for each step of your code and run your debugger.   Another quick way thing to try is to print debug statements in your controller, though this won't be as informative.  Also, enable debug logging on `org.springframework.web` and specifically look for `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping` and `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` to see what values you're getting and where it's stalling.  You can also use a profiler after trying these steps.  Sometimes it's a DB call, but often it's some incorrect loop logic.

Comment: Finally, sometimes it comes down to removing complex code/rolling back from a prior commit and gradually adding it back to isolate the issue.